# Found incompatible Titanium Modules: ti.map , version: 2.0.4

Tags: module, titanium, appcelerator

My situation

- Apple SDK 7.1
- Simulator version 7.1
- Titanium SDK 3.3.0G.A
- xCode 5.1
- Titanium Studio, build: 3.4.0.201409261227
- CLI version 3.4.0

Problem with [ti.map](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Map_Kit) modules : I try to start the app but I get this error :
[image]

I do not understand why now give me this error, I've uploaded an update of my app with the same configuration and I have not had any problems

the ti.map modules requires Titanium SDK > 3.2.0 and xCode > 5

Comment: Does the modules section in your tiapp.xml say * for the versions or does it have specific versions in there?  Perhaps remove the reference and add it again, maybe it will pick up the right version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have been hit by an "auto" update.... John Jardin has described a similar issue here: http://johnjardin.ukuvuma.co.za/2014/10/03/appcelerator-fix-ti-map-ios-upgrading-titanium-3-4-0/

Please let me know if it solves your issue?

/John